# How do I get the values TotVolElectra, TotVolGas from controller to component

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I can pass the list to the component but how do i pass the TotVolElectra, TotVolGas variables to the component. My code looks like:

```
/*  
    @Purpose      : Controller class of aansluitAdressenComponent
    @Author       : ir. Gianni Albertoe
    @Created Date : 30/03/2017

*/
public with sharing class aansluitAdressen {

    // Declare variables
    public Id currentId {get; set;}
    public List<Account> klaverContractList;
    public decimal TotVolElectra  {get; set;}
    public decimal TotVolGas {get; set;}


    public List<Account> getklaverContractList() {
    List<Account> klaverContractList =  new List<Account>();


        if(String.isNotBlank(currentId)){

            // Get the list related records
            try{
                klaverContractList  = [SELECT 
                    Parent.Name, ParentId, Type, RecordType.Name,Id,Name, Plaats__c, 
                    Straatnaam__c, Huisnummer__c,Huisnummer_Toevoeging__c, Postcode__c, 
                    Verzend_Straat__c, Verzend_Huisnummer__c,  Verzend_Huisnummer_Toevoeging__c, 
                    Verzend_Postcode__c, Verzend_Plaats__c, EAN_Code_Electra__c,
                    EAN_Code_Gas__c,Type_meter_aansluiting_Electra__c,Type_meter_aansluiting_Gas__c,
                    Verbruik_M3__c,Verbruik_laag_kWh__c,Verbruik_Hoog_kWh__c,Verbruik_enkel_kWh__c,
                    Teruglevering__c,Vestiging_doet_niet_mee_met_Tender__c ,Prive__c ,Cumulatie__c ,
                    Leegstand__c , Aansluitdadres_Type__c,
                    (
                        SELECT Name, EAN_Code_Electra__c, Verbruik_enkel_kWh__c,Verbruik_hoog_kWh__c, Verbruik_laag_kWh__c,
                            Type_Contract__c, Type_Of_contract_Stamkaart__C ,Account__r.Type_meter_aansluiting_Electra__c, 
                            Verbruik_M3__c,Leverancier_Gas__c, Leverancier_electra__c, Eind_Datum__c, 
                            Ingansdatum__c, EAN_Code_Gas__c,Tarief_Hoog_kWh__c, 
                            Tarief_Electra_Laag_kWh__c, Tarief_Electra_Enkel_kWh__c,
                            Vastrecht_Electra__c, Vastrecht_Gas__c, Tarief_Gas_m__c ,Contract__r.RecordtypeHulpVeld__c
                        FROM Contractaccounts__r 
                        WHERE Contract__r.RecordtypeHulpVeld__c='Gas' OR Contract__r.RecordtypeHulpVeld__c='Elektra'
                        ORDER BY Eind_Datum__c ASC
                    )                                          
                    FROM Account 
                    WHERE Aansluitdadres_Type__c !='Opgeheven' AND RecordType.Name = 'Aansluitadres' AND ParentId =:currentId 
                    ORDER BY Name ASC];                    

                for(integer i=0;i <= klaverContractList.size();i++){
                    TotVolElectra += klaverContractList[i].Verbruik_Hoog_kWh__c + klaverContractList[i].Verbruik_laag_kWh__c + klaverContractList[i].Verbruik_enkel_kWh__c;
                    TotVolGas += klaverContractList[i].Verbruik_M3__c;
                }
               /*     if(klaverContractList != null && !klaverContractList.isEmpty() && klaverContractList.size() > 0){ }*/   

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Exception in list : ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return klaverContractList; 

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a tad ambiguous. The correct answer here depends on whether this code is used in the controller (or extension) for a visualforce page that contains a visualforce component, or if it's used in the controller for your visualforce component.

Comment: @DerekF it is used in the controller for my visualforce component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your provided code is part of the controller for your visualforce component, you'll use the visualforce expression syntax (`{!<some expression>}`) to get values from your controller into your component.

In your controller, when you declared

```
public decimal TotVolElectra  {get; set;}
public decimal TotVolGas {get; set;}
```

you declared both of those as "properties" of your controller.

In visualforce (both pages and components), using `{!TotVolElectra}` and `{!TotVolGas}` will call the property's getter method, and return the result.

An example

```
<apex:component controller="yourController">
    <!-- an example of using expression syntax without a tag -->
    The total amount of electricity used was: {!TotVolElectra}
    <br />
    <!-- an example of using expression syntax as input to a tag -->
    Gas used: <apex:outputText value="{!TotVolGas}"/>
    <br />
    <!-- an example of using expression syntax and normal text as input to a tag -->
    <apex:outputText value="Used {!TotVolGas} units of gas, and {!TotVolElectra} units of electricity" />
</apex:component>
```